# Preserve metadata when converting .opus audio with embedded covers

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, metadata, ogg

Normally, when I run `ffmpeg -i "$name.$oldext" "$name.ogg"`, where `oldext` is any of `.opus`, `.m4a`, or `.flac`, all metadata is preserved. However, I've just found that in the specific case where the initial file is a `.opus` with an embedded cover image, no metadata is present on the resulting `.ogg`. Converting to `.flac` is the same. Converting to `.mp3` maintains the embedded cover but no other metadata.

What can I do to keep the metadata in this situation? Alternately, is there a simple script to copy metadata from one file to another in bulk. Many one-to-one copies, that is, not a one-to-many copy (I already can do that).

Current output of command:

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --dis
able-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth 
--enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio
 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --
enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enab
le-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-l
ibtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265
 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libie
c61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=harden
ed --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-
shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enab
le-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --en
able-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enab
le-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-li
brtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libss
h --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --en
able-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --
enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv --enable-version3 --disable-do
c --disable-programs --disable-avdevice --disable-avfilter --disable-avformat --disable-avresample --disable-postproc
 --disable-swscale --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libvo_aacenc --enable-libvo_amrwben
c
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[ogg @ 0x7e90a0] 1 bytes of comment header remain
[mjpeg @ 0x7eb020] Changeing bps to 8
Input #0, ogg, from '148 - Mewmore _ 'Zelda's Lullaby' (Remix) from The Legend of Zelda - Breath of the Wild.opus':
  Duration: 00:02:50.87, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 153 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      TITLE           : 'Zelda's Lullaby' (Remix) from The Legend of Zelda - Breath of the Wild
      ARTIST          : Mewmore
      album_artist    : Mewmore
      ALBUM           : Mewmore Remixes
      track           : 148
      GENRE           : Zelda Remixes
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      comment         : Cover (front)
      title           : 00001 - Mewmore _ 'Zelda's Lullaby' (Remix) from The Legend of Zelda - Breath of the Wild.jpg
[swscaler @ 0x7f9c60] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[ogg @ 0x816980] Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it.
Please consider specifying a lower framerate, a different muxer or -vsync 2
Output #0, ogg, to '148 - Mewmore _ 'Zelda's Lullaby' (Remix) from The Legend of Zelda - Breath of the Wild.ogg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: theora (libtheora), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k fps, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      DESCRIPTION     : Cover (front)
      title           : 00001 - Mewmore _ 'Zelda's Lullaby' (Remix) from The Legend of Zelda - Breath of the Wild.jpg
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libtheora
    Stream #0:1: Audio: vorbis (libvorbis), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      TITLE           : 'Zelda's Lullaby' (Remix) from The Legend of Zelda - Breath of the Wild
      ARTIST          : Mewmore
      ALBUMARTIST     : Mewmore
      ALBUM           : Mewmore Remixes
      TRACKNUMBER     : 148
      GENRE           : Zelda Remixes
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libvorbis
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> theora (libtheora))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (opus (native) -> vorbis (libvorbis))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libvorbis @ 0x85cb60] Queue input is backward in time
    Last message repeated 1 times
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       8kB time=00:00:22.54 bitrate=   2.7kbits/s    ^M[libvorbis @ 0x85cb60] Queue input is backward in time
frame=    1 fps=1.0 q=-0.0 size=       8kB time=00:00:45.99 bitrate=   1.3kbits/s    ^M[libvorbis @ 0x85cb60] Queue input is backward in time
    Last message repeated 4 times
frame=    1 fps=0.7 q=-0.0 size=       8kB time=00:01:09.31 bitrate=   0.9kbits/s    ^M[libvorbis @ 0x85cb60] Queue input is backward in time
    Last message repeated 3 times
frame=    1 fps=0.5 q=-0.0 size=       8kB time=00:01:32.72 bitrate=   0.7kbits/s    ^M[libvorbis @ 0x85cb60] Queue input is backward in time
    Last message repeated 2 times
frame=    1 fps=0.4 q=-0.0 size=       8kB time=00:01:56.22 bitrate=   0.5kbits/s    ^M[libvorbis @ 0x85cb60] Queue input is backward in time
    Last message repeated 3 times
frame=    1 fps=0.3 q=-0.0 size=       8kB time=00:02:19.43 bitrate=   0.4kbits/s    ^M[libvorbis @ 0x85cb60] Queue input is backward in time
    Last message repeated 1 times
frame=    1 fps=0.3 q=-0.0 size=       8kB time=00:02:42.63 bitrate=   0.4kbits/s    ^Mframe=    1 fps=0.3 q=-0.0 Lsize=    2385kB time=00:02:50.84 bitrate= 114.4kbits/s    
video:5kB audio:2351kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:7kB muxing overhead: 1.256185%
```

Changing the command to `ffmpeg -i "$name.$oldext" -map-metadata 0 "$name.ogg"` made no difference.

Side note I just noticed - according to the default thumbnails, the result is a video file (the original was audio). Attempts to listen in a music-only player failed. If I route it via `.flac` the resulting `.ogg` is audio.

Comment: Show the full console output of the command.

Comment: @Mulvya Added it.

Comment: Does `-map_metadata 0` help?

Comment: @slhck Nope, no difference.

Comment: Provide a sample input file if you can. Also [try a recent ffmpeg](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/): yours is ancient.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard `apt` says I've got the most recent, though I do see that that link shows more recent versions. I'm uncertain how to install from there without breaking the package-managed one. Or am I to manually find a new copy to update it whenever the need arises?

Comment: The link I provided will give you a recent `ffmpeg` binary that you can extract and just run. It won't interfere with the system or repo ffmpeg. Navigate to the directory containing it and run `./ffmpeg -i ...`, or provide the full path to it as in `~/Downloads/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i ...`. Or put it in a directory named `bin` in your home directory and then re-login–it will then be in your `PATH` and will run the new ffmpeg from any current directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After looking through SE and the ffmpeg docs for a few hours I finally found an easy solution: using `-map_metadata 0:s:a:0`, which copies metadata from the first input file (`0:`), first audio stream (`s:a:0`) (where the metadata is) to all output files (global metadata).